# not able to get the divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I faced one issue. The issue is as follows.
I want to divide a particular number with 7,9,11 but in every case i want to get the 
remainder as 1,2 3 accordingly. Could you please help me get the number and please explain how 
it works.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem on $x\equiv1\pmod 7,\equiv 2\pmod 9,\equiv 3\pmod {11}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let the number be $A$. Consider $2A+5$. This must be a multiple of 7, 9 and 11 from the conditions.

Hence $2A+5$ is a multiple of the LCM, which is $7\times 9 \times 11 = 693$.

So for example, since $\frac{693-5}{2} = 344$, 344 satisfies the conditions in the question. Check this. Other solutions will be $344 + 693 n$, which follows from the above.

---

Of course, Chinese Remainder Theorem is the way to go for the general case.

Comment: Is there anyway to identify something like $2A+5$ in general cases?

Comment: No, this is typical of certain CRT questions where making a special observation greatly simplifies the work, and hence avoids the need for young students to know the powerful CRT. See [example](https://brilliant.org/i/kCxu28/). The multiplication by 2 follows because we have an AP of difference 1 against an AP of difference 2.

Comment: Hi Calvin,Probably u didn't understand my question. I asked for a number for which i'll get the remainder as 1,2,3 if i divide the same no with 7,9,11 accordingly

Comment: @SouravBag It's a hint, not a complete answer. I've provided more details, and a particular answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin Could you please explain what logic you applied for choosing the equation like 2A+5?

Comment: @SouravBag There isn't a 'hard and fast' rule. It's more of pattern recognition, and taking advantage of the pattern in the question. If it was changed to remainder of 1, 2, 4 for divisors of 7, 9, 11, then I'd likely approach it via CRT directly.

Comment: @CalvinLin could you please help me solving this one too. The issue is as follows. 

I want to divide a particular number with 4,7,13 but i want to get the remainder as 1,2 4 accordingly. Could you please help me get the number and please explain how it works.

Comment: @SouravBag (In general) You should start another question. In this case, you want to look at $3A+1$. Note that this procedure isn't very reliable, and you should learn how to do CRT.