# Help me get the Divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to divide a particular number with $4,7,$ and $13$, but I want to get the remainder as $1,2$ and $4$ accordingly. Could you please help me get the number (If feasible at all) and please explain how it works.

Comment: Consider the following expressions: $x \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $x \equiv 2 \bmod 7$ and $x \equiv 4 \bmod 13$.  Try to work out with Euclidean algorithm and Chinese Remainder Theorem to determine the solutions.

Comment: Did you apply the answers from [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/427653/28900)?

Answer (score 4):

The system of congruence equations corresponding to your question are as follows:

$$\begin{align} x & \equiv 1\pmod 4 \\ \\  x & \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\ \\ x & \equiv 4 \pmod {13}\end{align}$$

To solve systems like this, use the Euclidean Algorithm and [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Here, you may simply use the Chinese Remainder theorem, as the $4, 7, 13$ are coprime.

Comment: another TU $\rightarrow +1$.

Comment: I know this TU ,so another time; TU $+^+$

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to find $n$ such that $$n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\n \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\ n \equiv 4 \pmod {13}$$   If the moduli are coprime, as here, the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) promises an answer.  There will be one less than $4 \cdot 7 \cdot 13=364$  See if the process described in the web page gets you there.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are relatively small, so we can conduct an informal search. First let's find a number that has remainder $1$ on division by $4$ and $2$ on division by $7$. A quick scan gives $9$.

Now add $28$ repeatedly until we get a remainder of $4$ on division by $13$.  If we do that, we bump quickly into an answer. But let's do that part slightly more "algebraically."

If we consider $9, 9+28, 9+28+28$, and so on, each time we add a $28$, we are adding  $2$ modulo $13$. We want to get to $4$ modulo $13$, that is, to $17$ modulo $13$. So we need to advance by $17-9$, "in $2$'s." That's $4$ advances, so a number that works is $9+(4)(28)=121$.

Naturally, for larger numbers, we will want to deploy more machinery, in particular the Euclidean Algorithm, and, perhaps, the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of my answer to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427653/not-able-to-get-the-divisor/427658?noredirect=1#comment916603_427658).

**Hint:** Let the number be $A$. Consider $3A+1$. This must be a multiple of 4, 7 and 13 from the conditions.

Hence $3A+1$ is a multiple of the LCM, which is $4\times 7 \times 13 = 364$. As such, $\frac{364-1}{3} = 121$  would be an answer. You can show that we must have $ A \equiv 121 \pmod{364}$.

---

As mentioned, you should approach this via CRT in general instead. This at times gives you a short cut calculation, but is very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know some elementary number theory, you should be able to work out the problem.

You need to determine the solution $x$ for the following expressions

$$x \equiv 1 \bmod 4$$
$$x \equiv 2 \bmod 7$$
$$x \equiv 4 \bmod 13$$

Since $4, 7$ and $13$ are coprime, we can determine the solutions for $x$.

Here is one of the ways I used to work out the computation (which is tedious and long).

We can rewrite those expressions as

$$(\alpha) \quad x = 1 + 4w$$
$$(\beta) \quad x = 2 + 7s$$
$$(\gamma) \quad x = 4 + 13v$$
$$\text{where } w, s \text{ and } v \text{ are integers.}$$

Perform substitution for $(\alpha)$ and $(\beta)$, so we have

$$1 + 4t = 2 + 7s$$

That is equivalent to

$$4w - 7s = 1$$

$\gcd(4, 7) = 1$ divides $1$, so we can apply Euclidean algorithm.  By the Euclidean algorithm, we obtain

$$\overbrace{7}^{\text{given}} = \overbrace{4}^{\text{given}}(2) - \overbrace{1}^{\text{remainder}}$$
$$4 = 1(4) + 0$$

Since zero remainder occurs during this process, we can rewrite the first expression as

$$4(2) - 7(1) = 1$$

The general solutions for this expression are

$$\begin{array} \\ 
 w = 2 + 7n & \\ s = 1 + 4n & \text{where } n \text{ is any integer}
\end{array}$$

*You can check these solutions by substituting them for $4t - 7s = 1$ to see if you get $1$.*

Substitute one of those expressions for one of the first two equations (for instance, substitute $w$ for the first expression.), so

$$x = 1 + 4(2 + 7n)$$
$$x = 1 + 8 + 28n$$
$$x = 9 + 28n $$
$$\text{Let's indicate } x = 9 + 28n \text{ with } (\theta)$$

However, we are not done yet since we found the solutions for the first two equations.  We need to also find the solutions that also work for the third equation.  With $(\gamma)$ and $(\theta)$, follow the previous steps, so we have

$$9 + 28n = 4 + 13v$$
$$5 = 13v - 28n$$

$\gcd(13, 28) = 1 | 5$, showing that the gcd of those terms divide $5$, so we are good.  By Euclidean algorithm, you should get

$$28 = 13(2) + 2$$
$$13 = 2(6) + 1$$
$$2 = 1(2) + 0$$

For this part, rewrite the first two expressions as

$$2 = 28 - 13(2)$$
$$1 = 13 - 2(6)$$

So by substituting the first equation for the second one, we have

$$1 = 13 - (28 - 13(2))(6)$$
$$1 = 13 - (28(6) - 13(12))$$
$$1 = 13 - 28(6) + 13(12)$$
$$1 = 13(1 + 12) - 28(6)$$
$$1 = 13(13) - 28(6)$$

Multiply both sides by 5, so we have

$$5 = 13(65) - 28(30)$$

The general solutions are

$$\begin{array} \\
v = 65 - 28z & \\
n = 30 - 13z & \text{where } z \text{ is any integer}
\end{array}$$

Thus, the general solution is

$$x = 9 + 28(30 - 13z)$$
$$x = 9 + 840 - 364z$$
$$x = 849 - 364z$$
$$\text{where } z \text{ is any integer}$$

You can verify that is the solution by substitution or math programs.

**Note:** Here is another [method](http://www.math.okstate.edu/~wrightd/crypt/lecnotes/node21.html) (with example) you can use to work out the problem.